# AFNetworking + HTTPS (Identity not verified)

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, afnetworking-2

I need to fetch the records from my Web-Server through `https` protcol. My API calls has Basic Authentication. Now, am trying this with `AFNetworking` version 2.0x

After work around and find out simplest way to add Basic authentication [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12440149) Now, i am getting problem with `https` call. When i execute my code,

```
NSDictionary *params = ....;

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [SBAPIManager sharedManager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

@try {
    [manager POST:@"Create" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success - %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Exception - %@", exception.description);
}
```

Am getting below response only,

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x7fd268560900 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myapi.com/Create, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://myapi.com/Create}

I found the [github fixes issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/82080963b89a1dd1e5f0bd0df036f645c6f78d31) But, [AFNetworking 2.x](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) has `(instancetype)policyWithPinningMode:(AFSSLPinningMode)pinningMode;` by default. How could i integrate this into my constraint.

Anyone has idea on this?

Comment: it's looks like problem in your server. When I hit that server in browser or advanced rest client it's returning nothing. You can use below reusable code for service call https://github.com/SSamanta/SSRestClient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I found the answer by myself. I have fixed my problem with the code below,

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:API_URL]];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES; // not recommended for production
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

If we want to pin AFNetworking to AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, we must add the following one line, which will provide the result.

> manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES; // not recommended for production

Reference: [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#allowing-invalid-ssl-certificates)